# Count number of commenters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There are Articles and Comments.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article, counter_cache: true
end
```

You can count number of comment by doing something like this:
@article.comments_count

The question is - how would you count the number of unique users who left a comment on a specific @article ? (note: a unique user can leave multiple comments)

here's a scenario:

> 1. comment - user_id(1)
> 2. comment - user_id(4)
> 3. comment - user_id(1)
>
> comments count = 3
>   commenters (unique user who left a comment) count = 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails has the wonderful [`distinct` query method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct) which makes this particular query easy to generate:

```
Comment.where(article_id: article.id).select(:user_id).distinct.count
```

which generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "comments"."user_id") FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."article_id" = ?
```

The benefit of this approach is you allow the database to do the heavy lifting. The database will often be several orders of magnitude faster than manipulating the objects directly in Ruby.

If you're willing to modify your `Article` class as follows:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commenters, through: :comments, source: :user
  has_many :unique_commenters, -> { distinct }, through: :comments, source: :user
end
```

you can also use the following code to generate a query:

```
article.unique_commenters
```

which generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "users"."id" = "comments"."user_id" WHERE "comments"."article_id" = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) and [`uniq`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq)

`@article.comments.uniq.pluck(:user_id)`

or just `pluck`

`@article.comments.pluck("DISTINCT user_id")`

Answer (score 0):

```
article.comments.collect(&:user).uniq{|user| user.id}.count
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use Ruby's `Set` for this:

```
unique_commenters = Set.new

comments.each do |comment|
  unique_commenters.add comment.user
end

unique_commenters.to_a
```

You could also just do `commenters.uniq!` on the collection, but I guess that is less efficient.

Answer (score -1):

The best way I know is create a scope:

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article, counter_cache: true  

  scope :count_by_user ->(user) { where(user_id: user.id).count }
end
```

Then:

```
@article.comments.count_by_user(user) # 2
```